# Thymeleaf: how to localize fragment?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, thymeleaf

I have few Thymeleaf based pages. On every page I'm including fragment with menu.

**Is there a way to localize fragment itself?**

I don't want to put same localized strings for menu items into every page *.properties file.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean including a separate fragment based on user locale?

Comment: No. I want to have separate .properties file for fragment.